# How to order my MySQL records ? | MySQL - WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am creating a website, for a client based on WordPress. My client want's in home page to display articles grouped under categories.

In example, let's say we have the categories "Cat A", "Cat B" and "Cat C". My client want's to  display the categories order in the following way "Cat B", "Cat A" and "Car C", in the home page, and then list 6 post from each category in home page.

Let's say this is the result I want to display:

```
Cat B
---------------------------
Cat B - Article #1
Cat B - Article #2
Cat B - Article #3
Cat B - Article #4
Cat B - Article #5
Cat B - Article #6

Cat A
---------------------------
Cat A - Article #1
Cat A - Article #2
Cat A - Article #3
Cat A - Article #4
Cat A - Article #5
Cat A - Article #6

Cat C
---------------------------
Cat C - Article #1
Cat C - Article #2
Cat C - Article #3
Cat C - Article #4
Cat C - Article #5
Cat C - Article #6
```

What I am looking for, is a way to order the categories to be displayed in the home page.

For now I have create a page in my WordPress dashboard, and from there I can sort my categories as I like, and then I can save the order option in the wp options page. The question is, how to order the categories in the front end based on the order in the backend.

Let's say that the categories are the following:

```
Categories
-----------------
Name   |  ID
-----------------
Cat A  |  100
Cat B  |  101
Cat C  |  102
```

In my wp_options table I can store the following array :

```
array(
    1 => 101,
    2 => 100,
    3 => 102
)
```

The array key can be the order sequence and the values the categories IDs.

Now, by knowing what is the sequence, how can I get that results with a single MySQL Query ?

Comment: `What I am looking for, is a way to order the categories to be displayed in the home page.` use a case statement to generate a column which you then use to sort `CASE Name When 'Cat A' then 2 when 'Cat B' then 1 when 'Cat C' then 3 end as SortByme`

Comment: @xQbert : Ops ! :) you are right. But assume, I am using the default WordPress tables, with wp_posts and wp_terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item (e.g. category or tag) in a taxonomy (for example categories or tags) has a name, a slug (short name that can go into a URL), and a description.

If you're willing to dedicate the description to ordering your category items, you could put 1 for Cat B, 2 for Cat A and 3 for Cat C in that field. You can do this from the dashboard.

Then, when you're retrieving the terms you could use this query to get the category ids in the appropriate order.

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug
  FROM wp_terms t
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
 WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category'
 ORDER BY tt.description, t.term_id
```

But that will tie up your description fields, or at least put some internal junk into a field that is used by a few (but not many) themes for display purposes.

You could also use the slug for this ordering purpose. Instead of 'catb' for a slug you could specify '1catb' for example (with '2cata' and '3catc' for your other slugs).  Again, it will have some effect on your display, this time on the form of some URLs in your site. Here's the query you might use in that case/

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug
  FROM wp_terms t
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
 WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category'
 ORDER BY t.slug, t.term_id
```

Turning a single wp_options row into a joinable table is far too hairy to be worth the trouble in my opinion, especially for an often-displayed website front door page. But you could use multiple wp_options rows for this. Give your wp_options names and values like this:

```
   option_name       option_value
   mycat_order_001       2
   mycat_order_002       1 
   mycat_order_003       3
```

Then use a query like this to get your category names in order.

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug
  FROM wp_terms t
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  JOIN wp_options o ON (    o.option_name LIKE 'mycat_order_%'
                        AND o.option_value = t.term_id)
 WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category'
 ORDER BY o.option_name, t.term_id
```

That will pull out your terms in the right order. The cost here is a more complex bit of code to update the wp_options table when your user specifies the desired order.

So there are some alternatives. Keep in mind that simple is good.